# When using SWFupload or Uploadify, do I need to edit my php.ini settings?

Tags: php, jquery, linux, uploadify, swfupload

I need to upload 100-200 MB files, solution that I found was to use Uploadify or SWFupload. (any takes on which is better to use?).

Now I'm going to set it up , but knowing that my server only accepts files under 3MB via regular post file, do I need to change the php.ini settings to have these large files upload or will the flash uploader take care of that for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process behind any client side scripting is processed server side. If you are using PHP then yes, you MUST change the configuration from `php.ini` to accept larger file size.

`SWFUpload` and `Uploadify` are client side - it means it runs on client browser and sends data to a file processor, in this case `PHP`, that file actually uploads the file and not SWFUpload or  Uploadify.

Comment: Since php handles the SWFupload and Uploadify file, like you said, I must change php.ini settings then. Ideally, only for that directory to prevent issues, correct?

Comment: You cannot change for a specific directory, but you can set only for one script with [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set) if your host allows it